# Elegant equivalent to C's vsscanf() in Java

Tags: java, parsing, variadic-functions, scanf

I need an equivalent to C's `vsscanf()` in Java. More detailled, I have this here:

```
private void parseString(String parseMe, String format, Object[] args) {
    // something like: vsscanf(parseMe, format, args);
}
```

Note that I have indeed read [about an equivalent for sscanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430022/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-sscanf-for-parsing-values-from-a-string-using-a-k), so it could be done easily from there. But I ask myself whether there is a more elegant solution than filling args with a for loop.

Also, it would be nice if the solution allows using varargs instead of an array, too. See below.

```
parseString(str, format, x, y, z);
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I want to scan, not print. Some confusion?

Comment: This is unlikely to be possible, given Java's pass-references-by-value semantics.  Also, the casts you'd be forced to do would introduce more awkwardness than the scanf syntax (as opposed to e.g. a `Scanner`) would save.

Comment: @LouisWasserman awkwardness? What does that mean in this context?

Comment: The only possible approach would be to take an `Object[]` -- not varargs -- and then to explicitly cast the results in that array: `(Float) array[0]`, `(String) array[1]`, `(Integer) array[2])`.  I feel pretty strongly that that's uglier than just doing e.g. `scanner.nextFloat()`, `scanner.next()`, and `scanner.nextInt()`.

Comment: I don't know a direct equivalent. One way to build it yourself is to use [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and parse the format string then use a `switch` statement to call `nextInt()` etc. depending on the pattern found.

Comment: In some common cases it might be simpler to just use `String`'s `split`. When things are more complicated, the `Scanner` way of doing it would just be more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.text.MessageFormat`. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String input="hello 1:2.3.4";
    MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat("{0} {1,number}:{2,number,integer}.{3,number}");
    Object[] data = form.parse(input);
    for(Object o : data) {
        System.out.println(o.getClass()+" : "+o.toString());
    }
}
```

Which produces the output:

```
class java.lang.String : hello
class java.lang.Long : 1
class java.lang.Long : 2
class java.lang.Double : 3.4
```

Of course, the format isn't as compact as that used by `scanf`, but it is out of the box Java.