# Split a long String into a specified size of smaller Strings

Tags: java, android, string

I am working on an SMS application for Android where I am sending a number of Strings of predefined size in a single SMS. At the sending side, I am concatenating a number of Strings of predefined sizes. Once I have received the SMS, I want to split the long String into smaller Strings based on their sizes.

Here is a simple code to explain what I have attempted:

```
// On the SMS sending side
String str1 = new String(new char[8]);
String str2 = new String(new char[4]);
String str3 = new String(new char[2]);
String str4 = new String(new char[2]);

String sendSMS = str1 + str2 + str3 + str4;

// send SMS
```

After receiving the data I want to seperate the combined String into data for str1, str2, str3, str4, given that I know the size of each small Strings.

So far I have found a number of answers on SO, all of which use split() function, however I do not have a seperating character token between the concatenated Strings. Instead, I want to use the knowledge of the size of each substring to get them. Something similar to [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) is what I am looking for.

Comment: So, you mean you need `String.substring()` ?

Comment: I have looked at `String.substring()`, however I have lots of Strings and it becomes quite cluttered to use substring for extracting each String. Is there a way I can use the sizes of each String into a single function call, that can split String into a String array of smaller Strings? As I said in my question, this would be something quite similar to `sscanf` in C++ (if it exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Assuming you were given `sendSMS` from your question and you wanted to get `str1` through `str4`, you might do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sendSMS);
str1 = getStringFromSb(sb, 8);
str2 = getStringFromSb(sb, 4);
str3 = getStringFromSb(sb, 2);
str4 = getStringFromSb(sb, 2);
```

And the `getStringFromSb` method:

```
String getStringFromSb(StringBuilder sb, int stringLength)
{
  String returnStr = sb.substring(0, stringLength);
  sb.delete(0, stringLength);
  return returnStr;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! This works as well as a number of other answers. I like your solution, although it is quite similar to just using an incremental index in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some sample code to do what you want...
However, it does no error checking which I will leave up to you.

```
String[] splitter(String input, int[] lengths)
{
    String[] output = new String[lengths.length];
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<lengths.length;i++)
    {
        output[i] = input.substring(pos, pos+lengths[i]);
        pos = pos + lengths[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I am now using `substring` function in a similar way as in your question. However, I also like the 'Stringbuilder' solution below.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a solution like this:

```
int index = 0;
String str1= sms.substring(index, str1Length);
index += str1Length;
String str2 = and.substring(index, str2Length);
Index += str2Length:
```

....

You can create a Helper class to do this:

```
Class SmsExtractor{
     Int lastVisitedIndex = 0;
     String msg;

     Public SmsExtractor (String msg){
         This.msg=msg;
     }

    Public String extract(int length){
         String m = msg.substring(lastVisitedIndex, length);
         lastVisitedIndex += length;
         Return m;
    }
 }
```

And use it :

```
SmsExtractor e = new SmsExtractor ( receivedMsg);
String str1 = e.extract(str1Length);
String str2 = e.extract(str2Length);
```

...

Another until method from SmsExtractor :

```
Public String[] extractAll (int[] lengths){
    String [] msgs = new String[lengths.length];
    For( int I =0; I< lengths.length; I++){
        msgs[I]= extract(lengths[I]);
    }
    Return msgs;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know in advance the size of the small String, you can calculate the index of each one from the large String. you can use the `substring(startIndex, endIndex)` function to do that.

[Here is an example](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-substring-method-example/)

You can use this function inside your own utility function like this

```
List<String> extractSmallString(String longString, List<Integer> smallStringSize) {
    ArraysList<String> extraction = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;
    for (int size : smallStringSize) {
        extraction.add(longString.substring(i, i + size);
        i += size;
    }
    return extraction
}
```

Comment: I have looked at `String.substring()`, however I have lots of Strings and it becomes quite cluttered to use substring for extracting each String. Is there a way I can use the sizes of each String into a single function call, that can split String into a String array of smaller Strings? As I said in my question, this would be something quite similar to `sscanf` in C++ (if it exists)

Comment: Why don't you create your own function taking a list of the small string size using internally the `substring` function and returning a `List<String>` ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/driedler/java-sscanf/tree/master/src/util/sscanf) library: It's an implementation for sscanf in java:

https://github.com/driedler/java-sscanf/tree/master/src/util/sscanf

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430022/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-sscanf-for-parsing-values-from-a-string-using-a-k) question too.